# How to get the Resources/Config folder path in Symfony2 Controller?

Tags: php, symfony

How would I get the path to the Resources/config folder as a string in a controller context in Symfony 2?

I have tried looking into the container, but I did not spot anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no built in method to fetch it, but it's easy to figure out.

From within a controller:

```
__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'
```

In fact, you'll see your bundle's Extension class using it in its `load()` method.

Comment: Check out the DependencyInjection folder in your bundle and look in the Extension class.

Comment: I am not sure: `__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'`  renders  `/var/www/html/Symfony2/src/Mario/MyBundle/Bundle/Controller/../Resources/config`, doesn't it?

Answer (score 7):

Or you could get the `kernel` service and then run

```
$kernel->locateResource('@NameOfBundle/Resources/config/filename');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$this->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . '/config';
```

getRootDir() always points to app folder.

Comment: In what context is $this?